# How to generate n random numbers from a list of m numbers in java?

Tags: java, collections, random

For example I have a list of 20 numbers and i try to random generate six of them without repeating them. Any ideas?

Comment: I would venture to guess that the answer to this is on this forum hundreds of times.

Comment: Probably more.  But regardless, when asking a homework question, it's always best to show us your good faith attempt at a solution.

Comment: ahhh good old days of Java homework...what a life that must have been

Answer (score 6):

If you have a `java.util.List` you could simple [shuffle it](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) and [pick the first](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) six.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way is to randomly shuffle the list and then take the first six elements:

```
List<Number> population = ...your list of 20 numbers...
Collections.shuffle(population);
List<Number> sample = population.subList(0, 6);
```